# sending data from frontend (angular) to backend (laravel) and send api post request through (laravel)

Tags: php, angular, laravel, api, hubspot

Hi i have 2 domain 1 for main website `www.something.com` and another for `apis.something.com`

- the **main** website `www.something.com` is frontend(**angular**) in html there are form with inputs
- the **subdomain** is `apis.something.com` is backend **laravel** which used for connect all apis with frontend the request for sending contact information to `hubspot` api

the problem is when i sending `api post request` (hubspot API) through client side **angular** directly i have ***CORS error***

### Note:

- `hubspot` blocked any post request through client side by **CORS**
- and if i send the request through backend (**laravel**) and send the
  header `allow origin` it accept and send the html normal html with
  **blade in laravel** which manually created **not through angular**

**the desired**

i want to `send the request` form which in **angular** in main website `www.something.com` and send it to **laravel** second apis subdomain `apis.something.com` then send the **api post request** to the `hubspot` api through **laravel** not through **angular** .

**Scenario:**

**angular** (frontend) form `www.something.com`  --> **laravel** (backend) `apis.something.com` --> **hubspot** api

**Angular Code :**

> sending.component.html

```
<form
    #pInputs="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)="form.valid && sendRequestData2(pInputs.value)"
    (ngSubmit)="form.valid && sendRequestData()"
    #form="ngForm"
    autocomplete="nope"
  >
<input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              [(ngModel)]="user.name"
              #name="ngModel"
              class="form-control"
              id="booking-name"
              placeholder="Enter your full name here"
              [required]="true"
            />
<button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-blue  text-white  brs25 pl50 pr50 brs22"
          i18n="@@send_request_now"
          [disabled]="!form.valid"
        >
          Send Request Now
        </button>
</form>
```

> sending.component.ts

```
export class SendSurgeryRequestFormComponent implements OnInit {
private readonly DEAL_URL = 'http://www.something.com';
  user = {
    name: ""
  };

  constructor(private bookingService: BookingService,private router: Router, private http:HttpClient) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {}

 sendRequestData2(data){

    const url = this.DEAL_URL;

    var payloads = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.http.post(url,
      payloads).subscribe((result)=>{
      console.log("the result", result);
      });
      console.warn(payloads);
    }

  goHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

**Laravel Code :**

> Laravel route

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key');
    
Route::post('https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact?hapikey=??????????????????', 'HubspotApiController@create');
```

> Laravel Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HubspotApiController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function create(Request $r)
    { 
        $arr = [
            'properties' => [
                  [
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'value' => $r['name']
                  ]           
                            ]
               ];


        $post_json = json_encode($arr);
        $client = new Client([
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
         ]);            
        
        $res = $client->request('POST',[
        'body' => $post_json]);
        return "Contact Created!";
        
         
    
        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: cors is a frontend thing. More specifically, browser thing. That is perhaps why you get cors issues in the angular app. And, the access control header you shared in route needs to be added to either index.php or a middleware, or use a cors library

Comment: ok but if i did that i got the same error .

Comment: please if someone can help i need to fix this problem ASAP .

Comment: Im sorry but I am not very competent in this area, I only know basics, but, why dont you try fruitcake/cors library? https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: @user3532758 thanks for trying help but i don't have problem with CORS through backend i want to transfer from angular (frontend) to laravel(backend) then post the request through laravel backend to hubspot api .

Comment: Oh no sorry I completely missed the gist of your question. Sorry. Maybe I can help with Guzzle but I still do not fully understand your question, I'm guessing your problem is the second point under notes. Could you perhaps elaborate that point?

Comment: Also, can you check which status code you get after guzzle request? Maybe do a `dd($res->getStatusCode())` right after your request